# Integrating $\int_0^{2} x e^{\ln(2)x}$

Tags: calculus, integration

How would I do this integral. I have tried the following.

$\int_0^{2} x e^{\ln(2)x}$

$u=x$ $dv=e^{\ln2(x)}$ $du=1$ $v=\frac{1}{\ln(2)}e^{\ln2(x)}$

$x\frac{1}{\ln(2)}e^{\ln2(x)}-\frac{1}{\ln(2)}\int e^{\ln2(x)}$

$x\frac{1}{\ln(2)}e^{\ln2(x)}-\frac{1}{ln(2)}\frac{1}{ln(2)}e^{\ln(2)(x)}$

Comment: I see well what I meant is 2^x= e^ln(2)x

Comment: Dont just change $1$ title!!!

Comment: Please, please, please don't forget to add the $\operatorname{d}\!x$ at the end of integrals when the variable is $x$. Leaving it off is a little like saying the *area* of a 2cm by 3cm rectangle is 2cm! The $\operatorname{d}\!x$ refers to the "width" of the areas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks good to me. Don't forget to evaluate the *definite integral*. I'd suggest "cleaning up" the final expression. For example, in terms of the corresponding indefinite integral,:

$$F(x) = \dfrac x{\ln 2}e^{\ln(2) x} - \dfrac{e^{\ln(2) x}}{(\ln 2)^2} + C  = -\ln 2\cdot e^{\ln(2) x}\left(x + \ln 2\right) + C$$ for example.

Now simply evaluate $F(2) - F(0)$

Comment: I see thanks for looking it over it helps because I can not be sure I am doing the problem correctly

Comment: Yes, you seem to have the "gist" of integration by parts. Your posts today have been progressively improving! In this post, my answer is just a suggestion for presentation of the result.

Comment: @FernandoMartinez: You can always differentiate an answer you get to see whether you are right.

Comment: @amWhy: You are always supportive! +1